# windows 7.5 dynamic content compression iis

Tags: iis-7.5, compression

I have followed plenty blogs explaining how to enable iis7's dynamic content compression.
These all seem to be based on windows server 2008.

I try to do the same on IIS7.5 installed on a windows 7 pc. and the block is greyed out. This is because the module is not installed.

How to I add the module in windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Performance Features.

Activate the checkbox "Dynamic Content Compression". Click OK.

Comment: nice. thanks. will tick as answer as soon as system lets me

Comment: oops, sorry took a while for me to do that. soz